# Changing the height of block container dynamically in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We have a requirement to generate PDF using FOP.  Here I am facing an issue with changing the height of block container dynamically in XSLT.  I have tried with setting minimum & maximum height.  If that is the case, if we give less content, the height will reflect in PDF according to that only.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to post more of your question. A block-container will be sized to the content unless you are specifying the height (when using Apache FOP):

Sample FO:

```
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="10pt" left="10pt" width="2.5in" border="1pt solid silver" background-color="#f4f4f4">
            <fo:block margin="5pt">Kasd elitr voluptua autem voluptua amet possim id soluta laoreet tincidunt elitr sed quod consetetur velit eos diam. Magna gubergren rebum diam accusam gubergren nisl ipsum lorem ullamcorper gubergren assum sea suscipit amet eos et lorem. Amet kasd sit diam ipsum dolor no odio. Esse stet ad sanctus dolor hendrerit ut nonumy ipsum dolor dolor takimata lorem sit facer. Mazim tempor ut est. Dignissim erat consequat dolore diam eirmod ut. Sit nonumy stet. Sit kasd invidunt sadipscing lorem elitr lorem ut. At diam sed eirmod id ea lorem lorem consetetur rebum takimata labore exerci dolor soluta. Assum tempor invidunt adipiscing gubergren ut ad nonumy ea eu consequat lobortis diam eirmod amet et volutpat minim gubergren.</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="80pt" left="40pt" width="5in" border="1pt solid silver" background-color="#f4b4c4">
            <fo:block margin="5pt">Kasd elitr voluptua autem voluptua amet possim id soluta laoreet tincidunt elitr sed quod consetetur velit eos diam. Magna gubergren rebum diam accusam gubergren nisl ipsum lorem ullamcorper gubergren assum sea suscipit amet eos et lorem. Amet kasd sit diam ipsum dolor no odio. Esse stet ad sanctus dolor hendrerit ut nonumy ipsum dolor dolor takimata lorem sit facer. Mazim tempor ut est. Dignissim erat consequat dolore diam eirmod ut. Sit nonumy stet. Sit kasd invidunt sadipscing lorem elitr lorem ut. At diam sed eirmod id ea lorem lorem consetetur rebum takimata labore exerci dolor soluta. Assum tempor invidunt adipiscing gubergren ut ad nonumy ea eu consequat lobortis diam eirmod amet et volutpat minim gubergren.</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="140pt" left="100pt" width="3in" border="1pt solid silver" background-color="#b4b4f4">
            <fo:block margin="5pt">Kasd elitr voluptua autem voluptua amet possim id soluta laoreet tincidunt elitr sed quod consetetur velit eos diam. Magna gubergren rebum diam accusam gubergren nisl ipsum lorem ullamcorper gubergren assum sea suscipit amet eos et lorem. Amet kasd sit diam ipsum dolor no odio. Esse stet ad sanctus dolor hendrerit ut nonumy ipsum dolor dolor takimata lorem sit facer. Mazim tempor ut est. Dignissim erat consequat dolore diam eirmod ut. Sit nonumy stet. Sit kasd invidunt sadipscing lorem elitr lorem ut. At diam sed eirmod id ea lorem lorem consetetur rebum takimata labore exerci dolor soluta. Assum tempor invidunt adipiscing gubergren ut ad nonumy ea eu consequat lobortis diam eirmod amet et volutpat minim gubergren.</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
```

And the output shows the height of each of the three is the height of the contents:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.I have two block container.According to the height of first block container,i need to set the height of the second block container.Can anyone help on this?

Comment: It is best and appropriate to ask separate questions in a new thread. Unless you are clarifying that this was your real original question. Then you should change your question content.